# Share data between chunks in quarto shiny document

Tags: r, shiny, quarto

A simple thing but is there any way to share objects from one chunk (here: `data-chunk`) with the server code (here: `server-chunk`)? I get an error that `server-chunk` can't access `faithful2`:

> Error: object 'faithful2' not found

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html
server: shiny
---

```{r data-chunk}
faithful2 <- faithful
```


```{r}
sliderInput("bins", "Number of bins:", 
            min = 1, max = 50, value = 30)
plotOutput("distPlot")
```

```{r server-chunk}
#| context: server
output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
   x <- faithful2[, 2]  # Old Faithful Geyser data
   bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
   hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white',
        xlab = 'Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)',
        main = 'Histogram of waiting times')
})
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer turns out to be using the `context` chunk option. You can read all about it here (translating the rmarkdown chunks into quarto chunks): https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_shiny_prerendered.HTML

For my example, it would look something like this:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html
server: shiny
---

```{r data-chunk}
#| context: setup
faithful2 <- faithful
```


```{r}
#| context: render
sliderInput("bins", "Number of bins:", 
            min = 1, max = 50, value = 30)
plotOutput("distPlot")
```

```{r server-chunk}
#| context: server
output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
   x <- faithful2[, 2]  # Old Faithful Geyser data
   bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
   hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white',
        xlab = 'Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)',
        main = 'Histogram of waiting times')
})
```
````